# clear function not working on storageMap angular 8 localstorage

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have an angular 8 app and am currently using the @ngx-pwa/local-storage package to have a localstorage.

I am using storageMap because as it says in the official package page:

*"New since version 8 of this lib, this service API follows the native Map API and the new upcoming standard kv-storage API, except it's asynchronous via RxJS Observables.
It does the same thing as the LocalStorage service, but also allows more advanced operations. If you are familiar to Map, we recommend to use only this service."*

I have been able to use set, get and keys just fine but am running into trouble with the function clear(), this function seems to do nothing at all or maybe I am using it wrong. I call clear, and then after the function keys and get all keys so the storage was not cleared.

My Code:

```
import { LocalStorage, StorageMap } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private storageMap : StorageMap ){

    this.storageMap.clear();

    this.storageMap.keys().subscribe({
      next: (key) => {
       console.log(key);
      },
      complete: () => {
       console.log('Done');
    },
  });
}
```

}
}

Comment: Subscribe to the Clear function `this.storageMap.clear().subscribe(() => {});`

Comment: @GopeshSharma you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the subscribe, my mistake. Here is the correct working function:

```
  this.storageMap.clear().subscribe({

      next: () => { },
      error: (error) => { }

    });
```